# Installing php4 on ubuntu 11.04

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, ubuntu-11.04

I need to install php4 to run a specific module that is no longer compatible with php5. I'm running ubuntu server 11.04 64bit. And as I expected the php4 packages are no longer available. Does anyone have a source for installing php4?

PS. Before anyone posts saying php5 is better "BLAH BLAH BLAH" I need php4 for a very specific reason and comments explaining the reasons why I should be using php5 over php4 are not helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just compile the source from the php site, you don need special ubuntu source code.
I have literally just done it on a Ubuntu 11.04 VPS to check it was that easy. I had to install one extr package "flex"

```
wget http://uk.php.net/distributions/php-4.4.9.tar.gz
tar zxf php-4.4.9.tar.gz
cd php-4.4.9/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

I didnt make the apache module, I haven't looked into that. It was a 32bit VPS I cant imagine it would not be as easy on 64bit.

Comment: and what about the libapache-mod-php4 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get older releases from http://www.php.net/releases/

Comment: Im looking for a ubuntu source I would like to avoid manually compiling it if possible

Answer (score 1):

I'd figure you're going to find it difficult to get hold of a prepackaged php4 release for Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty) and may have to consider manual compiling.

However... I am not sure how successful this may be but you could try the package which was released for Ubuntu 6.06 (Dapper).

URL: http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/php4

---

If there is any possibility to get updated version of the module you're trying to run for php5 then go with that. Although it does sound as though you've already looked.